# scanf reading "Enter" key

Tags: c, scanf, carriage-return

Why scanf doesn't work when I type "Enter" in the code below?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
 char *msg = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
 do{
        scanf("%s",msg);
        printf("%s\n",msg);
 } while(strcmp(msg,"")!=0);
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you see in the msg array after scanf?

Comment: scanf skips the white space looking for your string. Enter ( newlines ) are whitespace.

Comment: Charlie, there is a way to scanf DO NOT skips whitespace?

Comment: @vs06, there are two options in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of scanf() wait char-string, separated by whitespaces, enters, etc. So, it just ignores ENTERs, and waiting for "real non-empty string". If you want to get empty string too,
you need to use

```
fgets(msg, 100, stdin);
```

Comment: In C - exists stdin/stdout/stderr. in C++ exists ciin/cout/cerr (as same as C's stdin/stdout/stderr).

Answer (score 6):

The `"%s"` in `scanf("%s",...` skips over leading whitespace (including "Enter" or `\n`) and so patiently waits for some non-whitespace text.

Best to take in a `\n`, use `fgets()`.

```
char msg[100];
if (fgets(msg, sizeof msg, stdin)) {
  // success
```

If you *need* to use `scanf()`

```
int result = scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", msg);
if (result != 1) handle_rump_line_or_end_of_file_or_IOError();
```

This will scan in 1 to 99 non-`\n` chars and then append a `\0`.  It will then continue to scan 1 more `char` (presumably the `\n`) but not save it due to the `*`.  If the first character is a `'\n'`, `msg` is not changed and the `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

---

Edit (2016): To cope with lines that begin with `'\n'`, separate the scan that looks for the trailing `'\n'`.

```
msg[0] = '\0';
int result = scanf("%99[^\n]", msg);
scanf("%*1[\n]");
if (result == EOF) handle_end_of_file_or_IOError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanf looks through the input buffer for the specified format, which is string in this case. This has the effect of skipping your whitespaces. If you put a space between wording, it skips the space looking for the next string, similarly it will skip tabs, newlines etc.  See what happens if you put a %c instead. It will pick up the newline because it is searching for a char now, and '\n' constitutes as a valid char.

If you want the same effect while getting whitespace, change it to a %c and remove the newline escape character at the print statement.