# Why does this float array element print properly, but not this double array element?

Tags: c

I'm learning the basics of C right now.
I am trying to input data into an array. After some trial and error, I've found that I can do what I need to using a float array as opposed to a double array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   float x[4]={2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5};
   scanf("%f",&x[3]);
   printf("%f",x[3]);
   return 0;
}
```

The user input `3` would result in `3.000000`

However in this version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   double x[4]={2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5};
   scanf("%f",&x[3]);
   printf("%f",x[3]);
   return 0;
}
```

The user input `3` would result in `5.500001`

Why is this, and how can I properly enter values to/print out the array values?

Comment: Use `%lf` for double. E.g `scanf("%lf",&x[3]);`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @BLUEPIXY I've never seen that type before.

Comment: To fix this problem **enable compiler warnings** (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) when you compile and do not accept code until it compiles without a single warning. Read the warnings -- they tell you exactly what the problem is. Try it on your question code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have [memory trampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) due to use of incorrect [format specifiers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) First, the corrected example, with less "noise".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   double x = 5.5;
   scanf("%lf", &x);
   printf("%lf", x);
   return 0;
}
```

Second, you should try and avoid `scanf()` in general for string parsing, and considering reading on a per-line basis (ie: `fgets()` or some other mechanism), and then writing a parser. There is a plethora of closed/dupe questions on this site for questions like yours alone. Plus, other things, [like newlines being left in the input buffer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794268/scanf-reading-enter-key)

Finally, three good points:

- [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) notes: use `gcc -Wall -Wextra` to catch all compiler warnings. Append `-Werror` if you want to force yourself not to allow any warnings to get by).
- Look into learning how to to use `gdb` to debug programs. It's dead simple: compile with debug symbols and debug mode (and zero optimizations) configured via: `gcc -O0 -ggdb`, and then `gdb my_program_name`; joy!).
- Consider building your programs with stack smash detection enabled (`gcc -fstack-protector-strong`). It will intentionally "crash" (assert) your programs early if you're doing something very wrong, like what happened in your example. It lets you discover serious memory trampling issues during testing rather than in production. Now isn't a bad time to learn about valgrind, strace, ptrace, helgrind, perf, etc, while you're at it.

Best of luck!